How can i mock require.config in jest test cases
require.config({
    
});
 
require([
    "jquery"
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //perform function
    });
});

I tried defining require.config function.
But it does not help getting error
TypeError: require.config is not a function
Any leads will be helpful
